# knitr output outside margins in pdf

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am using knitr to include R code in a LaTeX document. However, the following input

```
<<tidy=TRUE>>=
x <- c(0.11111111, 0.22222222, 0.33333333, 0.44444444, 0.55555555, 0.66666666, 0.77777777, 0.88888888, 0.99999999)
x
@
```

generates the following output

[image]

As you can see, the code is printed outside the margins of the box. How can I contain the code output inside the box?

Comment: The width of the code blocks is the same as `options("width")`. You can change the width using `options(width = [desired_width])` where `desired_width` is the number of characters the should be displayed on a line.

Comment: @Benjamin where can I set this option? Is it possible to set it for a single chunk at a time?